# Symfony 2.8 TinyMCE install bundle error

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce, composer-php

i am on symfony 2.8, and my php version is 5.5.9.
i'm trying to install TINYMCE bundle from composer. I used this command line:

> php composer.phar require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle='1.0'

i had this message error:
[image]

i tried with v2.0 but same problem.

Have you an idea ?

Thank's a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that in your composer.json's config section you have platform requirements that conflict with the bundle.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

You could try installing the requirements using the option `--ignore-platform-reqs`:

```
composer require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle --ignore-platform-reqs
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This will momentarily lift the specified platform requirements. Obviously if they are in place, because they are actually needed - and since they were put there deliberately, at least at some point they were - this might break things on production. So be careful and look at the above option first (updating or removing the platform requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either of these two commands:

```
composer.phar require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle='1.0'
composer require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle='1.0'
```

I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but it might.